# Python Shorthand If - 0 interpreted as false in calculation result

Tags: python, math, boolean-logic, conditional-operator

```
for i in range(0,len(A) - 1): 
   cand = (A[i] + A[i + 1]) / 2
   cand2 = i + 2 < len(A) and (A[i] + A[i + 1] + A[i + 2]) / 3 or cand
   A[i] = min(cand, cand2)
```

I've written the above code to compute the minimum average of the next two & three  elements of an integer array. For example, if we have the array `[2,3,5,6]`, on the first iteration `cand` will be `2.5` and `cand2` will be `3.33` so `A[0]` will be updated to `2.5` and so on.

This code works, except when `(A[i] + A[i + 1] + A[i + 2]) / 3` is `0`. In this case, the `or` statement executes and `cand2` gets set to `cand`.

I'm pretty sure this is because Python interprets the `0` as `False` and executes the `or` statement - how can I fix this though?

Comment: Yes, Python considers `0` to be a falsy value. What do you mean with "Shorthand if"? If you wanted to create a ternary if, the syntax is `<true-value> if <contition> else <false-value>`. Chaining `and`/`or`s can do some tricks, but it makes it hard to follow what you wanted to do [esp. without parens around them]

Comment: got it - I think the if else approach would resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you wanted to do a ternary if here, that would work like this:

```py
for i in range(0,len(A) - 1): 
   cand = (A[i] + A[i + 1]) / 2
   cand2 = (A[i] + A[i + 1] + A[i + 2]) / 3 if i + 2 < len(A) else cand
   A[i] = min(cand, cand2)
```

You chained them with boolean operators, which maybe can work, as in python they do some tricks (an `and`-chained expression will return the first Falsy value of the chain, or the last value if all are Truthy - - - an `or`-chained expression will return the first Truthy value or the value if all are Falsy), but that makes your program a lot harder to understand.

Anyway, you might want to consider using a regular `if` construct here for best readability.

> [Some unspoken rules are:](https://blog.finxter.com/python-one-line-ternary/#Python_Ternary_Pep8_Pythonic)
>
> - The if branch should be the most likely one.
> - Don’t use nested ternary operators (use plain multi-line if ... elif > ... then ... statements instead).
> - Don’t use long ternary operators with complicated expressions (again use multi-line if statements instead).

```py
for i in range(0,len(A) - 1): 
    cand = (A[i] + A[i + 1]) / 2
    if i + 2 < len(A):
        cand2 = (A[i] + A[i + 1] + A[i + 2]) / 3
    else:
        cand2 = cand
    A[i] = min(cand, cand2)
```